# Правильно ли расставлены запятые при уточняющих обстоятельствах времени?

Tags: пунктуация

При осмотре РЛ турбины в мае 2014 г., через 2 года после нанесения на них упрочняющего покрытия и последующей эксплуатации энергоблока, не выявлено следов эрозионного разрушения покрытия лопаток.

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, здесь все на месте. А какие у Вас сомнения, ведь Вы, насколько я могу судить по Вашим прежним сообщения, очень грамотный человек?

Comment: Нет, дело в том, что эти запятые добавила я, но просто я еще немного сомневаюсь - вот и решила проверить.

Answer (score 0):

Да, запятые расставлены верно.